# Laravel form model saving error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

Whenever I am updating the data instead of getting updated the data is getting saved as new entry. 
Add task page

```
@extends('master.masterPage')
@section('content')

{!!Form::model($task,['url'=>['employeeTask.update',$task->id], 'class' => 'well form-horizontal']) !!}

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::Text('userAssigned', null,array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Employee Name')) !!}


    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
   {!! Form::Text('title',null,array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Title')) !!}


    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
    {!!Form::Textarea('description',null,array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Description')) !!}

    <!-- Text input-->
   {!! Form::Text('client',null,array('class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Client Name')) !!}

   <div class="form-group">
   {!!Form::Text('completionDate',null,array('class' =>'formcontrol','placeholder'=>'Date' )) !!}

    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
    {{Form::Submit('Save',['class'=>'glyphicon glyphicon-send'])}}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Route: web.php**

```
Route::resource('employeeTask','employeeTaskController');
```

**Employee Task Controller File Name: employeeTaskController**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Webpatser\Uuid\Uuid;
use App\Model\task;

class employeeTaskController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $data= task::all();
        return view('userPage.employeeTaskManagement')->with('data',$data);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
        return view('userPage.addTaskPage');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
        $task = new task([
            'id' => Uuid::generate()->string,
            'userAssigned' => $request->employeeName_txt,
            'title' => $request->title_txt,
            'description' => $request->description_txt,
            'client' => $request->clientName_txt,
            'completionDate' =>date('Y-m-d',strtotime($request->completionDate_txt)),
            'status' => $request->status_dd,
        ]);
        $task->save();
        return redirect('employeeTask')->with('message','task has been saved Successfully');
    }


    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $task= task::find($id);
        return view('userPage.editTaskPage')->with('task',$task);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
        $task = task::find($id);
        $task->userAssigned = $request->employeeName_txt;
        $task->title = $request->title_txt;
        $task->description = $request->description_txt;
        $task->client = $request->clientName_txt;
        $task->completionDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($request->completionDate_txt));
        $task->status = $request->status_dd;
        $task->save();
        return redirect('employeeTask')->with('message','task has been Updated Successfully');        
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Please check as whenever I am pressing save it is going to `employee.store` route instead of `employee.update`

Comment: try this Route::resource('employeeTask','employeeTaskController@update');

Answer (score 0):

If you check in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#resource-controllers) `POST` would be routed to the `store` method, `PUT/PATCH` would be routed to the update method.

What you could do is call the [updateOrCreate](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#other-creation-methods) method, so you would need to change your store method as

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $task = task::updateOrCreate(
        [
            'id' => Uuid::generate()->string // Pass in the ID to cross check
        ],
        [
            'id' => Uuid::generate()->string,
            'userAssigned' => $request->employeeName_txt,
            'title' => $request->title_txt,
            'description' => $request->description_txt,
            'client' => $request->clientName_txt,
            'completionDate' =>date('Y-m-d',strtotime($request->completionDate_txt)),
            'status' => $request->status_dd,
        ]
    );

    return redirect('employeeTask')->with('message','task has been saved Successfully');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line:

```
{!! method_field('put') !!}
```

After this line:

```
{!!Form::model($task,['url'=>['employeeTask.update',$task->id], 'class' => 'well form-horizontal']) !!}
```

So, laravel will know you need to update the data and use method **update()** instead of **store()**

Comment: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 251:

Comment: **Change:**
{!!Form::model($task,['url'=>
**To:**
{!!Form::model($task,['route'=>